# Mongoose's geoNear method not returning results

Tags: node.js, mongoose, geospatial, api-design

I'm receiving an error from the console when I test my API. I'm trying to push the results returned from the geoNear method into an array, but rather than returning an array with documents of near-by locations, it returns *undefined*. Even if there's no query string containing coordinates in my URL, my API should at least respond with an empty array. Something definitely went wrong down the road, and I'm really stuck on this one. The error message is as follows:

```
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Forrest\Desktop\loc8r\app_api\controllers\locations.js:39:10
```

"Loc" is the name of my model, and my controller looks like this

```
module.exports.locationsListByDistance = function(req, res) {
    var lng = parseFloat(req.query.lng);
    var lat = parseFloat(req.query.lat);
    var point = {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [lng, lat]
    };
    var geoOptions = { 
        spherical: true,
        maxDistance: theEarth.getRadsFromDistance(20),
        num: 10
    };
    Loc.geoNear(point, geoOptions, function(err, results, stats) {
        var locations = [];
        results.forEach(function(doc) { // Can't read property 'forEach' of undefined
            locations.push({
                disance: theEarth.getDistanceFromRads(doc.dis),
                name: doc.obj.name,
                address: doc.obj.address,
                rating: doc.obj.rating,
                facilities: doc.obj.facilities,
                _id: doc.obj._id
            });
        });
        sendJsonResponse(res, 200, locations);
    });
};
```

Comment: Check the first parameter in callback - `err`. If there is an error thrown by mongoose, `err` is not undefined, when other parameters - undefined,

Comment: I really should've done my error-trapping before hand, so lesson learned. I just needed to remove an index from my MongoDB. Thanks a bunch!